# Path variable issue after installing google cloud sdk(MacOS High Sierra)

Tags: macos, unix, google-cloud-platform

Today I was trying to install google-cloud-sdk from this given offocial link by google [this one](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads). After installation I noticed error in accessing python and other terminal commands. I echoed the $PATH variable and it has only one entry `/Users/faiz/google-cloud-sdk/bin`.

I checked /etc/paths and .bash_profile but they look fine.
I think there is some file that overrides these commands and resets the $PATH variable. Can anyone help rectify this problem?

Comment: Check the rest of [The Bash Shell Startup Files](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill It got solved. I've marked the answer. btw Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out little silly. I removed the path to google-cloud-sdk from .bash_profile and the problem got solved.